# nginx reverse proxy not working when multiple ports defined for REST api

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a next js app which I deployed on port 3000 and set the proxy 3000 on nginx.

Now I have my custom Node js Backend server which I want to run on the same server on different port 5000.

I setup the nginx like this

```
location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
location ^~ /api {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass    http://localhost:5000;
            
        }
```

I have no issue with accessing the app on example.com.
I setup the location /api for connecting the server.js / api fetching.

when I fetching like this

```
axios.get(example.com/api)
```

its returning error -- Cannot GET /api/

but when I set the nginx location proxy like this

```
proxy_pass    http://localhost:5000/;
```

with a forwar slash, its working and axios is fetching the data successfully.

But whenever I am trying to fetching another route from the server.js file like

```
axios.get(example.com/api/credential)
```

Its showing error again like this

```
Cannot GET //credential
```

Returning with double slash // credential

the only '/' route working from the server.js by fetching example.com/api

without the forward slash on proxy, its returning error. can not GET /api or can not GET api/credential

please help.
Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I fixed with the **Ivan's** answer. Now I have new issue with that config.
I am using socket.io beside the axios. So whenever I am trying to connect through socket.io
my client socket code is ..

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("https://example.com/api");
```

and server socket config is ..

```
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
```

Now when the page loads, the console is logging..

```
GET https://example.com/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O4UTf4l 404 (Not Found)
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should always prefer

```
location /prefix/ {
    ...
}
```

over the

```
location /prefix {
    ...
}
```

unless you are proxying a single API endpoint rather than a whole API (or another web app). When you use an URI prefix with the `proxy_pass` directive (that is, `proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;` rather than `proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;`, the trailing slash counts as an URI prefix here), nginx will strip the prefix specified in `location` directive from your request URI and prepend it with the prefix specified in `proxy_pass`. Use

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
}
```

and your `/api/credential` request URI will be correctly passed to your upstream as `/credential`.

Comment: Hi Ivan. Thanks for your answer. I helpd me and you saved my day. Now I have new issu with the socket.io. Please see the updated question.

Comment: I think you should use some different prefix for the websocket communications, e.g. `/ws` rather than mix it with the `/api` calls. You also should proxy WebSocket connections in a [special way](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html), however you already did it in your config. Unfortunately `socket.io` isn't the area of my competence, consider asking this as a separate question, maybe StackOverflow will be a more appropriate site to do it.